# Photoswipe - Scrolling should keep image opened Responsive JS PhotoGallery

Tags: javascript, api, slider, lightbox, photoswipe

I currently am using Photoswipe. I would like to know how to prevent the image from closing each time I scroll away from the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean with "swipe away" (swipe up/down/left/right?), and you didn't provide any code that shows your implementation.

So, the only possible answer at this stage is: read the documentation.
http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html

Those might be the options you are looking for:

```
closeOnScroll: false
closeOnVerticalDrag: false
```